# Switching from TextView to ListView in Android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, listview, textview

So, I've been following this [Vogella ContentProvider](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#contentprovider) tutorial sent to me by a friend, and if you look at the end of section 6.3 you'll see that he says:

> If you run this application the data is read from the **ContentProvider** of the People application and displayed in a **TextView**. Typically you would display such data in a **ListView**.

Since I'm new to working with android (and programming in general), I just changed the TextView tag in the main.xml to ListView, and as expected, when I run the app in the emulator, it crashes.

On-demand code:

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java File:

```
package de.vogella.android.contentprovider;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactsActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    TextView contactView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactview);

    Cursor cursor = getContacts();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

      String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
      contactView.append("Name: ");
      contactView.append(displayName);
      contactView.append("\n");
    }
  }

  private Cursor getContacts() {
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
        + ("1") + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";


    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
        sortOrder);
  }

 }
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, can someone point me in the right direction or tell me how to switch it from TextView to ListView?

Also, this is unrelated, but I downloaded the adt bundle and sometimes it doesn't generate the R.java file correctly, it doesn't make any changes to the R.java file and leaves it as the default one that gets generated when you make any new android project, any ideas why?
Note: You don't have to answer this question to get your answer accepted.

Comment: ListView is a different object than TextView, you can't just cast from one to another. The ListView can consist of a list of TextView's. Other than this, for me to be able to help you, you would need to provide the code you are working with. As for the R.java, that is usually caused by an error in an XML file, which causes the project compilation to not work. Also in addition, it is convenient to enable Project->Build Automatically in eclipse.

Comment: I would start by reading the ListView guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html and the Contacts guide http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html.

Comment: @LuckyMe Added the code upon your request.

Comment: @twaddington Thank you for the guides, I'm in the middle of reading them.